# Issues Splitting a Large Database

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm wondering if someone may have some insight into an issue I've encountered....

I have a database in Access 2016. Still in the design stage, but essentially it's a reporting tool for mainframe batch processes.  The thing is, it's big.  I have one table in specific that holds event data which is currently a little over 1 million rows.

A few days ago, when the table was around 500,000 rows I was able to split it without an issue, it worked fine, got a front end, a back end, everything was linked, all was well. That was a test run.  So of course I went back and kept working on a master copy all which is a single unsplit database.  Now, a few days later with more data imported, the table is up to over 1 million rows and the thing won't split.

Each time I try I get an error saying "The search key could not be found in any record".  Looking online, I see that in most cases this is due to corruption of some kind, and the most common response is a leading space in a field name.  I've searched every table and every field, no spaces to be found. I've compacted and repaired several times.  Everything in the database works fine, and no errors are seen, all forms, queries, macros and code work without a single problem, but the splitting wizard has an issue each time.  I delete half the rows in the table, and it works.

Does Access have a problem splitting large tables out? Do I need to split with less data, then import it back in?  Easy enough, but I'm wondering if I am maybe getting corruption somewhere that I'm just not seeing in any code or query returns?

I appreciate any insights you may have.

Thanks,
Gord

Answer (score 0):

Well, once you split, you should continue developing split. There is little (if no reason) to go back to an un-split development model.
And the beauty of such a setup is that then your development and application part will be VERY small.

There is no need to try and develop with some big elephant in the same room.

Another bonus?

Well, for the most part “most” things work fine when split, but there are a few things that work a “little bit” different. As a result, you don’t want to spend say a week, or a month of developing. Split, and then find 20+ bugs.

In other words, developing split as you “go along” means that any issue crops up right now, and not some can kicked down the road. In other words, splitting early in the development cycle means you STAY split for rest of the lifetime of this project.

When you first start out?

Well, because you designing and changing table structures so much? Well, then if split, this part of the development cycle will be MORE painful if un-split.

If un-split?
Then to change a table structure you:

Exit front end (FE)

Open up back end (BE). Add columns, maybe create or setup some relationships etc. Maybe even add a new table. Hey, some table is large and you search on a column? Then add an index. So, your “general” maintains of the data, compact repair etc.? All done in this BE.

Ok, all good?

Now close the back end.

Now, you go back to your front end.

You at this point should re-link your tables. (The linked table manager does this quick and easy).

And, if you added any new tables to the back end? Well, once again you use the linked-table manager and add those new tables.

So, a “bit” of extra work compared to un-split.

As noted, so, say for the first say week?

You are creating tables, modifying the structures, adding new tables. Setting up relationships. So, at this point, it just fine and ok to work un-split. And you NOT have a lot of data yet, if hardly any data in the system, right???

However, after a very short time then table changes (structures etc.) will calm down to a dull roar. So, this is about the time you should split.

ONCE split, you ARE NOT going back to the old un-split development model anymore.

And the beauty of this setup? Well, you can work with a “test” version of the data. Or re-link to the live production version.

So, say you are testing some code to delete row of data. What happens if you miss some criteria and delete all of the production data?

So, working as un-split in a typical development cycle for Access? You only do this for a short time, and then once you split, you should remain un-split.

And this also makes it REALLY easy to make a backup of your application part (separate from data). At the start of the day, you can drag a copy of your working application into the “previous” folder. Since the application has no data, it is going to be rather small – thus easy to back up and make a working copy.

There is LITTLE reason to work on a nice small application with a huge elephant in the room attached (the data part).

So, I strong recommend after splitting, you don’t attempt to go back to an un-split database.

Ok, what do do about this failing split issue?

File huge, not splitting with the wizard? Well, this obvious is ANOTHER GOOD reason to remain split!

What I would do is do the split manual. The steps the wizard does (or you manual) is very easy.

So, exit the front end. Now create a blank new database for the back end data.

Now, import the tables from the FE (front end).

If the import goes ok? This means you are home free!

Exit, and now re-open FE.

Simply delete the tables in your front end. Now do a compact.

Ok, now simply fire up the linked table manager, and browse to, and link to the back end. So the database splitter does nothing more (or less) then these simple steps.

So, you can split manually – give tat a try.

And giving the trouble you’re having right now? Well that is just another great and good reason to keep things split!

So, try a manual split.

Comment: That's really excellent advice, and I thank you.  I've been developing it for about 6 days, and it has definitely grown exponentially.  Initially as you said, I have been making a lot of changes to table design and structure to accomodate the type of reporting I need ,but you're correct, I shouldn't have to be making any further changes. I'm thinking of simply backing it up, deleting the data from the large table, splitting it then reimporting the table data from the backup into the split version, then using the split version as the master source for any further development.

Comment: All good.  I think once you get the large tables out to the separate database, you are on the  home stretch. Good luck!